The Boyer-Moore majority vote algorithm proof of correctness
First of all, here is the pseudo code for the Algorithm:
Initialize an element m and a counter c with c = 0
For each element x of the input sequence:
If c = 0, then assign m = x and c = 1
else if m = x, then assign c = c + 1
else assign c = c − 1
Return m

I really struggled to grasp the proof of the Majority Voting Algorithm from the Discrete Mathematics book by Kenneth Rosen. The proof goes as follows:

Proof: (adapted from Wikipedia) Let m be the majority element. Let n be a
number defined at any step of the algorithm to be either the counter,
if the majority candidate is m, or the negative of the counter
otherwise. Then at each step in which the algorithm encounters a value
equal to m, the value of n will increase by 1, and at each step at
which it encounters a different value, the value of n may either
increase or decrease by one. If m truly is the majority element, there
will be more increases than decreases, and n will be positive at the
end of the algorithm. But this can be true only when the final stored
element is m, the majority element.

Why does n being a positive integer imply that the candidate is indeed m? Since n is incremented whenever we encounter m, it could also be incremented if we encounter a different value, say x, when x is the candidate. Wouldn't that make it possible for the algorithm to output x instead of m?

This proof is a bit weird. I think it's easier to think about what happens in any given step. There are four situations, depending on whether the candidate is $m$ and what we see. If the candidate is not $m$ and we see an $m$, this $m$ "cancels out" another element, and so on. So if there are more $m$ than any other element, the algorithm works.

Indeed, it is strange. The author thought through what happens at each step and used a helper variable, n, in this case. You said, 'If the candidate is not m and we see an m, this m "cancels out" another element, and so on.' However, this explanation is not very clear to me; I would like a more rigorous proof. Thank you @MathieuRundström

It is annoying that the given proof uses m to refer to both the majority element and an accumulating register.  Don't do that.  Let r refer to the majority element.
n is defined as
$$n = \begin{cases} 
c & \text{ if } m = r \\
-c & \text{ if } m \ne r \\
\end{cases}$$
This is a formulaic definition.  At any step of the algorithm, you can look at the register c, look at the register m, and compute the value of n.
Since c cannot be negative, if n is positive when the algorithm finishes, it must be the case that $m=r$.

...  it could also be incremented if we encounter a different value, say x ...

That is completely irrelevant to the prior point.  It does not matter how n becomes positive.  You should be able to verify is true the above claim before proving that n will be positive when the algorithm finishes.

Lets say there are $N$ elements total, $M$ of which are our majority element, $2M > N$. For each of the $M$ occurrences of our element, it will be handled by one of the three rules you outlined:

If c = 0, then assign m = x and c = 1
else if m = x, then assign c = c + 1
else assign c = c − 1

Rules (1) and (2) accomplish the same effect: the current item is/becomes $m$ and $c$ is incremented, so we'll handle them together.
Let $M_{a}$ be the number of times that our majority element is handled by rule (1) or (2), and $M_{b}$ be the times its handled by rule (3). Each of the $M_{b}$ occurrences invoking rule (3) implies a preceding element that is not our majority element, so $N - M \ge M_{b}$. Similarly, in order for our final $m$ value to not be our majority element, $M_{a}+1$ non-majority elements would have to follow our $M_{a}$ invocations of rules (1) & (2). This gives us $N - M \ge M_{b} + M_{a} + 1$.
Since $M_{a} + M_{b} = M$, we have $N - M \ge M + 1 \Longrightarrow N \ge 2M + 1$.
This contradicts our definition of $M$ being a majority element above, so we conclude that $m$ must be our majority element.

Lemma 1: when $m == x$ and $x$ != $x'$, you can cancel $x$ and $x'$ out and the sequence will have the same output unless this sequence has only $2$ different elements.
For example, sequence $aabbcc$, you can cancel out $ab$. The result sequence $abcc$ will have the same output. Applying the same operation, the output of $abcc$ == the output of $cc$.
Proof: When the majority candidate == the element, the counter will $+1$. And at the next element, which is different from the majority candidate, the counter will $-1$. So the net change of counter is $0$. And the majority candidate remains the same.
Lemma 2: For any sequences, there must be at least one pair you can cancel out unless all the elements of this sequence are the same or the sequence is empty.
Proof: The first element = majority candidate. Thus, we can just keep checking the following elements until we find an element different from the first element.
Conclusion: If a sequence has majority element, we can always cancel out all the non-majority elements. Thus, the result sequence has the same output as the original sequence and only has the majority elements. Thus, it outputs the majority element.
Proof: we can only cancel out at most $1$ majority element each time because the elements of a pair must be different. Thus, each pair must have at least $1$ non-majority elements. The number of majority element must be larger than that of the non-majority elements. Thus, when all the non-majority elements are cancelled out, there must be at least $1$ majority element left.
I also do not understand the textbook answer. I spent few days to figure out this relatively easier proof. The proof of this algorithm is far harder than the implementation.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Did you really have to edit 40+ times!? Please keep edits to a minimum.
